# Same route parameters with different controllers' action methods causes an error in Asp .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action, attributerouting

I m using attribute routing feature of Asp .Net Mvc.
My first action is like below which is placed in SurveyController

```
    [Route("{surveyName}")]
    public ActionResult SurveyIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And my second action is like below which is placed in MainCategoryController

```
    [Route("{categoryUrlKey}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string categoryUrlKey)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I'm not using convention based routing.
Below is my RouteConfig.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        routes.MapAttributeRoutes();
    }
```

Now the problem is when i click to a survey it redirects to the MainCategory/Index route. I know it is because of same route pattern but i cant change this into another thing.
how can I handle this situation?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your survey view?

Comment: Are you using the `RoutePrefix` or `RouteArea` attributes at all?

Comment: it s empty at all @Ala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix the routes on your `MainCaregoryController`, either at the controller level like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("category")]
public class MainCategoryController : Controller {
```

**or** at the action level like this:

```
[Route("category/{categoryUrlKey}")]
public ActionResult Index(string categoryUrlKey)
{
    return View();
}
```

Routes should not clash. This route:

```
[Route("{categoryUrlKey}")]
public ActionResult Index(string categoryUrlKey)
{
    return View();
}
```

matches **any** string and passes that string value into the action, so without a prefix it will match:

```
http://localhost/validcategorykey
```

and

```
http://localhost/something/id/isthispointmakingsense
```

and your `categoryUrlKey` parameter would equal `"validcategorykey"` in the first instance and `"something/id/isthispointmakingsense"` in the second.

Now as for this route:

```
[Route("{surveyName}")]
public ActionResult SurveyIndex()
{
    return View();
}
```

This just won't work period.  This needs to be changed to:

```
[Route("survey/{surveyName}")]
public ActionResult SurveyIndex(string surveyName)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but actually i dont want to use any prefix in the route. I just want to display them like domain/categoryName and domain/surveyName. Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't possible because there is no way to tell the difference between _domain/categoryName_ and _domain/surveyName_ when `categoryName` and `surveyName` are both strings.

Comment: But they are different controllers? and so actions. You mean there is no logic when asp .net routes these urls to to the related controller and action methods?

Comment: Of course there is logic in _ASP.NET_ to map urls to routes. However, you have defined two routes whose patterns clash. `{categoryName}` and `{surveyName}` is the same as `{anything}` and `{anything}`, how are you supposed to differentiate intelligently? Your route pattern means match **any** string, it doesn't matter what you call the variable it is to be assigned to.

Comment: Then i have to put a convention before of the route parameter. Thanks for your responses